# Credentials for docker image AWS S3 - InvalidAccessKeyId

Tags: amazon-web-services, docker, amazon-s3

I am creating S3 bucket in that way:

```
docker run -d --name localstack -p 4566:4566 -p 4565:4565 -e SERVICES=s3 localstack/localstack

aws --endpoint-url=http://localhost:4566 s3 mb s3://my_conteiner
```

And now trying to create `PreSingedURL`

in ASP NET .Core in that way:

```
public string GeneratePresignedUrlAsync(string key)
{
    var request = new GetPreSignedUrlRequest
    {
        BucketName = _options.BucketName,
        Key = key,
        Expires = DateTime.UtcNow.AddHours(_expirationTime)
    };

    return _s3Client.GetPreSignedURL(request);
}
```

I am using this credentials to do this:

> "AWSS3": {
> "ServiceURL": "http://localhost:4566",
> "AccessKey": "test",
> "SecretKey": "test",
> "BucketName": "my_conteiner",
> "Region": "us-east-1"
> }

But I got messsage when trying open generated url:

```
<Error>
<Code>InvalidAccessKeyId</Code>
<Message>The AWS Access Key Id you provided does not exist in our records.</Message>
<AWSAccessKeyId>test</AWSAccessKeyId>
<RequestId>id</RequestId>
<HostId>id 
</HostId>
</Error>
```

When I use aws configure list command in localstack terminal I can see:

```
  Name                    Value             Type    Location
  ----                    -----             ----    --------
profile                <not set>             None    None
access_key                <not set>             None    None
secret_key                <not set>             None    None
region                <not set>             None    None
```

Do I miss something when building my image, should I use different values ​​for my keys?

Comment: Try running `aws configure` and set these values?

Comment: @ArpitJain I set access_key, secret_key, region and output format. No differents.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It work when I create AmazonS3Client in this way:

```
var credentials = new BasicAWSCredentials(_options.AccessKey, _options.SecretKey);
var config = new AmazonS3Config
{
    ServiceURL = _options.ServiceURL,
    ForcePathStyle = _options.ForcePathStyle,
};

_s3Client = new AmazonS3Client(credentials, config);
```

Additionally, when building Docker, I must have the configuration for credentials:

```
[default]
aws_access_key_id = test
aws_secret_access_key = test
output=json
region=eu-west-1
toolkit_artifact_guid=<guid>
aws_session_token = aws_session_token
```